# Is it possible to get a List of custom objects from Firestore?

Tags: android, list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore database for music:

```
ROOT
 |
 +-- shops {collection}
      |
      +-- shopId {document}
             |
             +-- shopName: "Awesome Shop"
             |
             +-- dvds {dvd object}
                  |
                  +-- dvdIdOne {object}
                  |     |
                  |     +-- name: "Led Zeppelin: Live in Seattle 1977"
                  |
                  +-- dvdIdTwo {object}
                        |
                        +-- name: "Queen: Live at AID 1985"
```

If I get the entire `shopId` document, is it possible to get the `dvds` object as a `List<DvdObject>`? Can the `dvds` object be mapped to a list of custom objects?

Comment: This is currently not possible.  You will have to write code yourself to convert a List<Map> to a List<DvdObejct>.

Comment: @DougStevenson I see, thank you very much Doug.